# I want to clean the console of the error: "GET http: // localhost: 4200 / assets / i18n / 1 / en 404 (Not Found)" @ Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-i18n

I want to clean the console of the error:

> GET http: // localhost: 4200 / assets / i18n / 1 / en 404 (Not Found)

I want to clean the console of the error:

> GET http: // localhost: 4200 / assets / i18n / 1 / en 404 (Not Found).

**custom.translate.loader.ts**

```
 getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    let loggedUser = this.authenticationService.getUserFromStorage()

    if (loggedUser.selectedOrganizationId === null || loggedUser.selectedOrganizationId === undefined) {
        return new TranslateHttpLoader(this.http, './assets/i18n/default/', '.json').getTranslation(lang);

    } else {

        return Observable.create(observer => {
            this.http.get('./assets/i18n/' + loggedUser.selectedOrganizationId + '/' + lang + '.json').subscribe((res: Response) => {
                observer.next(res);
                observer.complete();
            },
                error => {
                    //  failed to retrieve from api, switch to local
                    this.http.get('/assets/i18n/default/' + lang + '.json').subscribe((res: Response) => {
                        observer.next(res);
                        observer.complete();
                    })

                }
            );
        });

    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
   interval: any;
   firstNavigation: Boolean = true;
   locale: any;
constructor(
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private tokenService: TokenService,
    private updateService: CheckBuildReloadService
    ) {
    this.locale = (this.tokenService.getLocale() === undefined) ? 'en' : this.tokenService.getLocale();
    this.translate.setDefaultLang(this.locale);
    this.translate.use(this.locale);
    localStorage.setItem('lang', this.locale);
    if (environment.production) {
      this.updateService.initVersionCheck();

    }}
changeLanguage(lang) {
this.translate.use(lang);
// reload translation
this.translate.reloadLang(localStorage.getItem('lang'));
}}
```

Here is the console and network error
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try with ./ : this.http.get('./assets/i18n/default/'

Comment: it is difficult to tell by looking at partial code. but you can debug on XHR/fetch breakpoint for URL '/fr' and then you can trace the origin of your error

Comment: I can't tell if you're asking (1) why you get a 404 when requesting `/assets/i18n/1/en`, or (2) how can you stop making the request. I'm not sure what you mean by "I want to delete the service."

Comment: - Is not functional when I add "./".                                                                                        -- It is the two portions of codes which are responsible for error.

Comment: I want to clean the console from the following error only "GET http://localhost:4200/assets/i18n/1/fr.json 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Check .json is missing in the url.

Comment: We get "404" when the file "/ assets / i18n / 1 /" cannot be found  .                                     
I tried to test the existence of file generated in the project but, this is not the right solution@ Sam Fen